# При работе с устройством выключается экран

Tags: java, android

Я устанавливаю флаг на то чтоб экран был все время активен, но он почему то все равно гаснет

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorMagnet = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}
```

первые 3 строчки в onCreate...
Что я делаю не так?

Вот исправил код и все равно экран гаснет

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
    wl.acquire();

    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorMagnet = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```